# Unable to set default tags for every queues in Amazon SQS using nservice bus

Tags: c#, tags, amazon-sqs, nservicebus

Currently, I have to switch our messaging system to use AmazonSQS and due to pricing policy, we are obliged to put tags. But I do not found any method to add tags.

Below the method which won't work due to fact that this approach is expecting that the queues already exist and I can get URL of the queue:

```
public static EndpointConfiguration CreateEndpointConfiguration(BusConfig config)
    {
        var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration(config.QueueName);

        endpointConfiguration.LicensePath("license.xml");
        endpointConfiguration.SendFailedMessagesTo($"{config.QueueName}.Errors");
        endpointConfiguration.EnableInstallers();
        endpointConfiguration.UseSerialization<NewtonsoftSerializer>();
        endpointConfiguration.LimitMessageProcessingConcurrencyTo(10);

        endpointConfiguration.Conventions()
                             .DefiningEventsAs(type => typeof(IMessage).IsAssignableFrom(type))
                             .DefiningCommandsAs(type => typeof(ICommand).IsAssignableFrom(type));

        var transport = endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<SqsTransport>();
        transport.ClientFactory(() =>
        {
            var amazonSQSConfig = new AmazonSQSConfig()
            {
                RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USWest2
            };
            var client = new AmazonSQSClient(amazonSQSConfig);
            
            var addedTags = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            addedTags.Add("Team", "Development");
            addedTags.Add("Accounting ID", "number");

            var tagQueueRequest = new TagQueueRequest()
            {
                Tags = addedTags
            };

            client.TagQueueAsync(tagQueueRequest);
            
            return client;
        });
        transport.QueueNamePrefix("some-prefix");
        
        endpointConfiguration.Recoverability()
                             .AddUnrecoverableException<CustomException>();

        return endpointConfiguration;
    }
```

Can you provide solution for adding automatically tags during configuring endpoints?
Thank you for any help

Comment: You can check [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/CreateQueue.html#CreateQueue-create-queue) to see queue creation via C# code.  [CreateQueueRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/SQS/TCreateQueueRequest.html) class of AWS C# SDK have `Tags` property which you can populate to assign tags to the queue at the time of creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [NServiceBus integration with SQS](https://docs.particular.net/transports/sqs/) doesn't seem to support configuration of tags at the moment. You'd have to manually create your queues upfront with the appropriate tags or manually [add tags to existing queues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-configure-tag-queue.html).

You can raise feature requests for tag support on Particular Software's SQS transport repository here: https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.AmazonSQS

Comment: that's right. we are currently discussing inside a team and probably we will create fork of https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.AmazonSQS

but you know. The hope is dying the last :D maybe we are simply blind :D

Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! Forking might cause you some significant effort to keep the transport integration up-to-date in the long run. Depending on how often you're creating new queues, tagging them "manually" (or some script) might be the same effort without locking you into forking. I'd highly recommend raising an issue with Particular, that gives you at least the chance of this feature being integrated with the transport officially.